# Apache re-write from URL to Internal URL?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, iis, mod-rewrite

I have Outlook Web Access hosted on IIS Windows Server 2003 and the setup is weird from some other dude.

I have Apache listening on 8080

I want users to be able to type in something like: mail.mydomain.com/owa and get redirected the intranet at 192.168.1.1/owa

So my thought was use Apache on the same machine as IIS and have my users type in mail.mydomain.com:8080 and have mod_rewrite to 192.168.1.1/owa

So I created a .htaccess that is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://192.168.1.1/owa [R, NC]
```

I even tried:
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://192.168.1.1/owa [R, NC]

But that doesn't work, I try and hit mail.mydomain.com:8080 and I just get a blank page.

Any traffic on mail.mydomain.com:8080 I want re-directed to 192.168.1.1/owa

What am i doing wrong. Sorry about not doing http // as I am a new user it told me no.

Answer (score 1):

You need use mod_proxy or flag P, redirect doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^owa/?(.*) http://192.168.1.1/$1 [L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf file, make sure that the line saying:

```
AllowOverride None
```

inside of the `<Directory "<htdocs_dir>">` block is changed to:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

or

```
AllowOverride All
```

This will allow mod_rewrite to function.

[Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), see "Override"

Comment: that gets me part of the way, now I think that my ReWrite rule is not correct as I get an Internal Server error and the log tells me a bad delimiter. Time to see how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You running an internal DNS? Would be easier to set that address entry to the apache server instead.